# How to set first child in Expandable list view always selected when particular group is clicked?

Tags: android, android-listview, listener, expandablelistview

```
TaxiListAdapter list_adapter = new TaxiListAdapter(
                TaxiListActivity.this, groupHeader, hashMap);
        list_view.setAdapter(list_adapter);
        list_view.setOnGroupExpandListener(onGroupExpandListener);

private OnGroupExpandListener onGroupExpandListener = new OnGroupExpandListener() {

        public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {
            list_view.setSelectedChild(groupPosition, 0, true);
        }
    };
```

In above section list_adapter is set of list of Header with their child list and i put this list in Expandable list view, and list is showing properly. When i click any parent(Header) of list it is opening but it is scroll down and it show me last child data , I want it show me from starting in the layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
TaxiListAdapter list_adapter = new TaxiListAdapter(
            TaxiListActivity.this, groupHeader, hashMap);
    list_view.setAdapter(list_adapter);
    list_view.setOnGroupExpandListener(onGroupExpandListener);

private OnGroupExpandListener onGroupExpandListener = new OnGroupExpandListener() {

    public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {

    }
};
```